# Use RecyclerView in earlier versions of Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I want to use RecyclerView in my Android app. Following are the properties:

```
minSdkVersion="14" (ICS)
compile sdk version="21" (L)
Target sdk version="14" (ICS)
```

I added `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` under dependencies in build.gradle file.
When I'm adding RecyclerView in XML, I'm getting following error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
```

XML code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I want the application to run on all devices above ICS. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `RecyclerView` v7 support library to your `build.gradle`. There are multiple v7 libraries, each for specific features.

`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'`

Comment: @Jaguar you said you added the `appcompat` v7 library

Comment: Thanks. After this do I need to add any jar in libs?

Comment: @Jaguar no, the jar and resources will be imported from the line I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is in its own library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

For `targetSdkVersion 25/compileSdkVersion 25` and compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` you need to use compile `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'`

Versions needs to be same.